# When do I delete Redis keys in an Azure Website?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, redis

I'm building an Azure website as a learning experience, and I'm using Azure Redis instead of SessionData or TempData to store some user log-in info... am I understanding that's the "correct" way to do it? What I'm not sure of is when do I delete the key from the Redis cloud? I can put an expiration time on the key...but that would mean picking an arbitrary time that I think a user would be logged in. Does the key eventually get cleaned up when the ConnectionMultiplexer goes out of scope? There are commands to DEL a key...but when do I execute that command if the user doesn't consciously log-out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like all choices, the right choice will depend on exactly what you application does and what data it is storing.

Typically folks handle session data expiry using a sliding window for expiry i.e. they will keep extending the time out by N secs every time the session data is used (SET/GET). You can also invalidate all the data on explicit log off.